# Inspiron 3670 Install

Tags: 16.04

I want to install 16.04 on a newly purchased 3670 with Intel I5-8400 processor. The installs listed for 64 bit are all AMD based. Which version of 16.04 should I use for the I5-8400?

Answer (score 0):

amd64 is just the name of the processor arch. It *means* 64-bit and is not linked to the processor type.

You should install the amd64 version because your processor is 64-bit, and it should work fine (citation: I have it on an earlier-generation Inspiron).